# Accessing elements of multidimentional arrays with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

In the following:

```
<?php
$test = array(
    array("fName" => "Paul", "lName" => "Jones", "Age" => "31"),
    array("fName" => "Mike", "lName" => "Hunt", "Age" => "3"),
    array("fName" => "John", "lName" => "Doe", "Age" => "32")
);
?>

<pre> <?php var_dump($test) ?> </pre>

<?php
foreach($test[0] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . " " ;
}
```

?>

This outputs `Paul Jones 31`

How can I get it to output JUST the first names `fNames`?

i.e. `Paul, Mike, John`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach($test as $person) {
    echo $person['fName'] . " " ;
}

// output: Paul Mike John
```

Comment: I swear I tested that prior to asking the question and it didn't work ;) Oh well, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to iterate over the main array rather than an individual element in it.

```
foreach($test as $item) {
    echo $item['fName'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($test as $value) {
  echo $value['fName'] . ", " ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($test as $arr)
    echo $arr['fName'] . ', ';
```